# What's the meaning of Neumann BCs in heat conduction problems?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

What's the meaning of Neumann BCs in heat conduction problems?

Such as given here:

[https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~dommelen/pdes/style_a/svbex.html](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/%7Edommelen/pdes/style_a/svbex.html)

Why does one specify $u_x=g_0$ at the end of the rod. Rather than $u=g_0$?

Is it because it's assumed to "change", whereas the start of rod is thought to "have an initial value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of Neumann BCs as fixing the heat flux and Dirichlet BCs, of course, fix the temperature.

You could generally specify either; they're just different problems. For example, $\partial_x u =0$ on the endpoints would imply perfect insulation (no heat flux). On the other hand, you could specify $u=0$ which would say that the temperature is fixed at zero at the endpoints of the rod.